# use app.use() instead of script tag in node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I want to use bootstrap with nodejs, express
how to use

```js
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/js/jquery.min.js'));
app.use('/link', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'));
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'));
```

instead of

```html
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Uhm, what? `app.use` really has nothing to with script tags in the browser, unless you create some middleware that actually does that?

Comment: I do not know how to replace, please show me a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this code and succeeded, but not sure if that is the best

```js
app.use('/jquery.min.js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'));
app.use('/bootstrap.min.css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'));
app.use('/bootstrap.min.js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'));
```

```html
  <script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```